# How to point 2 different project to same domain name apache2

Tags: domain-name-system, apache2

I have 1 domain names registered.I also have 1 apache2 server at AWS. (running Ubuntu)
I have two directories /var/www/site1 and /var/www/site2 for same domain.

site1 ----> domain.com and site2---> domain.com/site2

------ site1-----

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

----site2-----

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName domain.com/site2
    ServerAlias www.domain.com/site2
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

my site1 is working .... pls help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

`ServerName` needs to be a domain name. It cannot be a path like you have tried.

Most likely you want to add the directory under your `domain.com` server, with a separate root directory.

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not for explaining basics how software works. Please study Apache's documentation to see how to configure your setup.

Comment: tanq @Tero --->alias /site2 /var/www/site2 this works for me